# GUI extension where to get Extensions.TridionDashboard.dl?

Tags: 2011, gui-extensions, 2011-sp1

Just want to know is any dll available from Tridion called Extensions.TridionDashboard.dll?

Comment: You can search it in your tridion installation directory. It would be good if you elaborate your question mentioning what problem you want to solve, to get good and accurate answers.

Comment: To make this question useful to others, perhaps it would be better to phrase it in more general terms of how one can check whether a DLL is shipped by SDL. (My guess would be that the Copyright property is a good enough way to tell, but that might not be bullet-proof)

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests, it must be a custom DLL created by someone and might not be a Tridion dll (owned/produced by SDL).

You may check with the owner of the code about this as I doubt you get any promising answer here

Comment: Yes pankaj i have the same doubt, also if you can help i am facing one more issue after upgrading from 2011 to 2011 SP1 we use http://localhost/WebUI/Editors/TridionDashboard/view/Dashboard.aspx for dashboard view  which internally resolve .ascx file under "Page" folder but now it give error "The file '/WebUI/Editors/Pages/WelcomePage.ascx' does not exist." but ideally it should take the file from '/WebUI/Editors/TridionDashboard/Pages/WelcomePage.ascx' what configurayion we need to change in this case? Hope i am able to convey my question if not i will raise a new one with proper contecx

Comment: That's definitely better as either a separate question or combined with your original question. It seems like you're having issues with an dashboard or welcome screen configuration. You could instead ask what the expected files are and/or describe what errors you're experiencing.

Comment: agreed with Alvin